# paypal form variables with shipping and billing address

Tags: php, paypal

I want to send the billing and shipping address separately to paypal, and after submitting the form paypal will send a mail with billing and shipping address to the admin. I am using **first_name, last_name, address1,address2** I need diffrent details, have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal doesn't disclose the buyer's billing address -- only the shipping address.  You can supply the buyer's shipping address, but not the billing address.  (If the buyer doesn't have a PayPal account, PayPal will use the shipping address as the billing address by default.)  If you absolutely have to have the buyer's billing address, you need to collect it and store it on your site before you send the buyer over to PayPal.

The proper variables for passing the buyer's shipping address are `first_name`, `last_name`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, and `country`.

Answer (score 0):

use naming convention like this ship_first_name, ship_last_name, ship_address1,ship_address2 and for billing bill_first_name, bill_last_name, bill_address1,bill_address2. think it will help you. thanks.

Comment: but in https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables there is not this type of variable

Comment: hope billing and shipping address are generating from your end. so you can define variable name like this

Comment: if paypal do not support those variables then how can we use them ?

Comment: If you absolutely must have actual billing address you'll have to do what Matt Cole says and save that locally prior to sending the user over to PayPal.